# Nodejs mongodb driver [2.0 - ] BSON reference replacement

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to use `BSON` reference of nodejs mongodb driver in a meteor project. But since version **2.0** it seems to be removed from the api. What I'm trying to use is [this method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/bson.html#bson-calculateobjectsize)

Therefore, what's the replacement of the reference `BSON` or atleast mentioned method ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's buried way down in the `MongoInternals` object, and it's only available on the server:

```
var testObj = {test: 'sadkllj'};
var size = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db.bsonLib.BSON.calculateObjectSize(testObj);
console.log(size); // 23
```